# how to replace string in golang with 'greedy principle' properly ？

Tags: string, go, replace

I try to mask strings but something goes wrong

Reproducible code is below and all old-new pairs is required, how to get `col1` instead of `col0b` ?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    r := strings.NewReplacer("a", "col0", "ab", "col1")
    s := "ab"
    fmt.Println(r.Replace(s))
}
```

I expect that strings could be replaced with max-length or greedy principle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#NewReplacer), replacements of NewReplacer are performed in the order they appear in the target string, without overlapping matches, so it will always follow the first-match basis. If it is allowed, I think you can workaround this by  reorganizing the replacing pair so that the longer string (`"ab"-"col1"`) is placed earlier than the shorter ones (`"a", "col0"`)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    r := strings.NewReplacer("ab", "col1", "a", "col0")
    s := "ab"
    fmt.Println(r.Replace(s))
}
```